# How did Rahab speak the language spoken by Joshua’s spies

Tags: language, joshua

Did the Israelites learn many languages in Egypt and pass them down (including to one of these two spies)? Is it known how Rahab was able to communicate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Abraham, Isaac and Jacob lived in Canaan before the Hebrew people moved to Egypt.

Moses lived for forty years in Midian before he led the people into the desert.

During the wandering in the desert, the Hebrew people frequently fought the neighboring peoples.

All these interactions provided opportunities for some of the Hebrew people to learn Canaanite languages.

Comment: There may also have been a lingua franca of some sort in the region. Israelites who knew this tongue--whatever it was--would be preferred for the job, and it's no small stretch for a harlot in a major city to have some knowledge of a common trade language as well.